# Sums not being calculated right

Tags: c#

Hi i am trying to calculate the sums of the submatrix of order K from a matrix of order M, but I am getting wrong result from the sums matrix. In my head the logic makes sense, I don't know what the mistake is.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shkruani te madhesine e matrices dhe madhesine e submatrices: ");
            int M;
            int K;
            int sum = 0;
            M = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            K = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] sums = new int[M - K + 1];
            int[] matrix = new int[M];
            Console.WriteLine("Shkruani vlerat e matrices: ");
            foreach (int i in matrix)
            {
                matrix[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= M - K; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < K; j++)
                {
                    sum += matrix[i + j];
                }
                sums[i] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < (M - K + 1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sums[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide some *example(s)*, please? Matrix, desired value and actual one?

Comment: For example if i enter M=5=K and but the values for M from 1 to 5 I get the result 5. which is wrong. The correct result would be 1+2+3+4+5

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I found the mistake, the foreach loop was not working as it should. I do not know the reason maybe they have changed the way it works, haven't worked on C# in 1 year.

Comment: Suppose, `matrix = int[] {10, 25, 40, 70, 100}` let `M = 4` and `K = 1`. What is the desired `sum` array and why?

Comment: The Problem is likely the foreach loop. you dont get the index with i, but the values of Matrix, which, in this case, are Always the same

Comment: You might wanna change `foreach(int i in matrix)` to `for(int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; ++i) matrix[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` instead of `foreach` loop

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
        foreach (int i in matrix)
        {
            matrix[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Use this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Explanation:
Because ***For-Each*** loop works with **value (iterate through value)** instead of index (May be what you want) while ***for*** loop works with **index (iterate through index)**.

Hope this helps.
Thank you.